# Alternative ways to set select element's value during validation of a form?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Normally I would do something like this:

```
<select name="myselect">
  <option value="opt1" <?=($_POST['myselect']=="opt1"?"SELECTED":"")?>>Option 1</option>
  <option value="opt2" <?=($_POST['myselect']=="opt2"?"SELECTED":"")?>>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

However this time I've taken a list of all the countries in a select from this website: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/376

To go through each of those and put in the validation will be insane.

There is a php solution in the comments but it seems somewhat inelegant.

Is there an alternative way to do this or something similar? I would prefer not to use javascript, and I'm not sure I want to rely on the browser caching.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// I'm using integers as key values in this example. Modify as needed.    
$countries = array(
  1 => 'Some Country',
  // etc...
);

// Sanitize as needed, casting to integer in my example
$selectedCountryCode = isset( $_POST['myselect'] ) ? (int) $_POST['myselect'] : null;

$select = '<select name="myselect">';
foreach( $countries as $countryCode => $countryName )
{
    $selected = $selectedCountryCode == $countryCode ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    $select .= '<option value="' . $countryCode .'"' . $selected . '>' . $countryName . '</option>';
}
$select .= '</select>';

echo $select;
```

Comment: brilliant idea. For all those who want it - here is a list of countries in a php array: http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/array-list-countries-en/

Answer (score 0):

Add countries to `value-label` array

Generate options with loop

```
foreach ($countries as $value => $label) {
    $isSelected = $_POST['myselect'] == $value ? ' selected="selected"': '';
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '"' . $isSelected . '>' . $label . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create select with an array like this:

```
$options = array('opt1' => 'Option1', 'op2' => 'Option2');
foreach ($options as $o => $v)
{
   if ($_POST['myselect'] == $o)
      echo '<option value="' . $o . '" selected="selected">' . $v . '</option>';
   else
      echo '<option value="' . $o . '">' . $v . '</option>';
}
```